# How to get object type

Tags: object, kineticjs

Given an arbitrary array of kineticjs objects there a way to get the object type?

```
var ary = new Array();

ary[0] = "Circle Obj";
ary[1] = "rect Obj";
ary[2] = "arc Obj";
ary[0] = "Circle Obj";
```

Please comment

Answer (score 1):

Yes, use `myObject.className`

```
ary[0]=new Kinetic.Circle({...});

console.log(ary[0].className); // returns "Circle"
```